# How to plot dates with matplotlib after pd.read.csv?

Tags: plot

I am having difficulties to plot a simple date/prices csv file which i imported into python using pd.read.csv. I am not able to transform my date column into datetime do you have an idea for this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
import datetime as dt
df=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\semdexcsv.csv',index_col=None,header=None)
df.columns = ["Date", "ClosePrice"]
x = df["Date"]
ff = np.array(x)
f = ff.reshape((-1,1))
y = df["ClosePrice"]
```

A sample of my df in python is :

```
    Date    ClosePrice
0   09/01/1991  197.15
1   16/01/1991  192.72
2   23/01/1991  195.76
3   30/01/1991  192.79
4   06/02/1991  193.3
5   13/02/1991  192.41
6   20/02/1991  188.14
7   27/02/1991  185.75
8   06/03/1991  186.88
9   13/03/1991  181.17
10  20/03/1991  176.9
11  27/03/1991  172.47
12  03/04/1991  170.1
```

I will want to have a simple plot diagram with dates in x axis and values in the y axis. Right now, I am not able to transform the date column into datetime.

Thank you very much

SB

Answer (score 0):

Add a `parse_dates=['Date']` to your `read_csv` method call. The method call then becomes:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\semdexcsv.csv',index_col=None,header=None, parse_dates=['Date'])
```